# Unwrap a 3D fingerprint (convert to 2D)

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh, fingerprint

I need to unwrap a 3D fingerprint (convert to 2D). I cannot just remove z coordinate and make it 2D. I need to unwrap it in a manner that it resembles as if the fingerprint would have been scanned as 2D at first place.

The input I am having is a ply file with just the x,y,z coordinates.

Any suggestion? Any software out there that will do it for me directly? 
I heard there are some spring solvers that will do it for me. Any idea how can I implement it?

I want to do it the easy way rather than getting into too much complexity.

Thanks!

Comment: 3D how? Is it a curved surface (like the tip of your finger is) with ridges? Or is it already flattened with ridges?

Comment: What kind of surface is it on? You'll want a mapping/projection from that surface to a flat surface. Or a 2d parameterisation of the surface.

Comment: yes, its a curved surface. Its a 3D point cloud data. I have identified the ridges and valleys points of the dataset. The dataset is not flattened with ridges.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in a field called distance geometry. This discipline attempts to project N dimensional points into lower dimensions, whilst attempting to preserve the original distances as closely as possible.

The simplest algorithm I have ever encountered to solve this problem is:
http://www.dimitris-agrafiotis.com/Papers/jcc20078.pdf

I coded this up in a very short time.

Welcome to SO btw....

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot just remove z coordinate and make it 2D. I need to unwrap it
>   in a manner that it resembles as if the fingerprint would have been
>   scanned as 2D at first place.

Well, that's pretty much the way it would be done, isn't it?

Perhaps with a filter on `z` so that points far away from the "camera" are not scanned?

Comment: No, this is incorrect. You have described "truncation" which is not guaranteed to preserve maximum information about the higher dimensions. Think about projecting a cube into 2d. Do you show a single face, or a view from a corner. Distance geometry concerns itself with preserving as much information as possible.

Comment: @Andrew: "Projection", when concerning a 2D representation, is almost always analogous to truncation. Unless you have some magic encoding going on (see: 3D glasses) this is the only way to transform 3D to 2D. It's the way that the movie industry functioned for about 80 years until the recent disappointing rise in the pointless "3D movie" money-grabbing scheme.

Comment: But projection can be done many, many ways. Some preserve more information than others. The OP was asking for the best way to do it. Distance geometry strives for the best way to do the projection, whilst losing the least amount of information.

Comment: @Andrew: Then this is not "incorrect", but one method amongst many.